# container level securityContext fsGroup

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to play with single pod multi container scenario.
The problem is one of my container (directus) is a node app that run as user 'node' with uid 1000

First try, I use hostpath as storage back end. With this, I need to change the host's directory mode with chmod manualy.

Now, I'm trying using longhorn.
And basicaly I don't want to change a host directory mod/ownership each time i deploy this deployment.

Here is my manifest

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: lh-directus
  namespace: lh-directus
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: lh-directus
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: lh-directus
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
        isGeneralDeployment: "true"
      volumes:
      - name: lh-directus-uploads-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: lh-directus-uploads-pvc
      - name: lh-directus-dbdata-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: lh-directus-dbdata-pvc
      containers:
      # Redis Cache
      - name: redis
        image: redis:6
      # Database
      - name: database
        image: postgres:12
        volumeMounts:
        - name: lh-directus-dbdata-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      # Directus
      - name: directus
        image: directus/directus:latest
        securityContext:
          fsGroup: 1000
        volumeMounts:
        - name: lh-directus-uploads-volume
          mountPath: /directus/uploads
```

When I Appy the manifest, I got error

```
error: error validating "lh-directus.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.containers[2].securityContext): unknown field "fsGroup" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecurityContext; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

I reads about initContainer ....
But Kindly please tell me how to fix this problem without initContainer and without manualy set/change host's path ownership/mod.

Sincerely
-bino-

Comment: I think you need to specify the securityContext fsGroup in the spec, not in a specific container, as indicated in the documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/. I don't fully understand what you want to achieve, but maybe you need to use runAsUser here? This applies individually to containers...

Comment: The setup you're showing here really isn't a best practice.  Consider what happens if you set `replicas: 3`: each replica will have its own copy of the two data stores.  You also should almost never use `hostPath` volumes, since you'll get separate storage if the replicas get scheduled on different nodes.  Splitting out the databases into separate StatefulSets, letting the cluster create the PersistentVolume objects for you, and avoiding local file writes from your application container would all be better practices.